# Common cookie with different Domain

Tags: php

Can we use a common cookie in PHP for different domains. e.g.  domainA.com and domainB.com (Not for subdomain) .If yes then how. Please explain me with an example. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are available for your domain and it's shbdomains only. However, a good solution would be to have a script working in a server that reads information from a neutral domain, and fetches the right information. For example: d1.com and d2.com both want to fetch the login details of a given member. They both turn to example, d1.com with the login data, which returns to them the member details, and they set their cookies accordingly, each on its own domain.